# How do I rotate my iPad application window to landscape in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4

In Xcode 3, I was able to select the rotation arrow at the top left of the window to design the window for the application in landscape. However, I can't find the same function in Xcode 4. Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I have the same question but was not successfully after reading this acticle. Or perhaps the Simulator is not able to rotate the aplication? I have still the Navigation Bar on the right side after turning the iPad Simulator to the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select your view, press cmd+option+0, click on the the shield icon "Show the attribute inspector" and then change Orientation to landscape.

Comment: That rotates the view correctly, but the window associated with the view is still shown in portrait. It's orientation setting is greyed out.

Comment: And I also have the issue that when I rotate the iPad Simulator, the view doesn't rotate with it, even though I return YES to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in the View Controller. I am using the default iPad application template, if that helps!

Comment: Sorry for the ranting; it wasn't until I went back to Xcode 3 that I realised the differentiation between the window and the view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Window orientation is not very intuitive (since the view and the controller are both controlled by the orientation setting in the "Simulated Metrics" dialog). It's actually controlled at the four corners of the window displayed in the view editor. Just click and drag the corners of the window to resize it.

Comment: I didn't even realize you could resize the window that way.  Duh!  Thanks for that tidbit of info.  People talk about an arrow to click to change orientation.  Any screenshot? I can't seem to find it.